# Check the next index column value and consecutive length of same value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if the next index column has the same value as previous index column and also get the consecutive same value length.

For example, there is a dataframe below, and I want to get the length of consecutive value of 0.

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 
a   1 0 0 1 1 1
b   0 0 0 1 0 0
c   1 0 1 0 1 0
d   1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Result:

- row a has two consecutive 0 values so the length is 2
- row b has three consecutive 0 values so the length is 3
- row c has no consecutive 0 value so the length is 1
- row d has no value of 0 so the length is 0

Additionally, if the first index is starting with 0, don't count until value 1 appears and start counting the length with the next 0.

- Applying this condition, the result of row b should be 2.

There are more than 1000000 rows in real data so for loop will take too long, so I want to know if there is a way to do this in pandas or in other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create `df1` for count consecutive `0` and get `maximum` value for `new1`. For second it is more complicated - get indices of first max value (here are max values `1`, so get indices of first `1`) and create mask for set `0` values by mask, so next `sum` omit first only `0` groups.

Also if only `0` rows it return wrong output, so necessary change condition with multiple for `~a.all(axis=1).values[:, None]` for prevent it:

```
a = df == 0
b = a.cumsum(axis=1)
df1 = (b-b.where(~a, axis=1).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int))

cols = np.arange(len(df.columns))
n = np.argmax(df.values, axis=1)[:, None]

mask = (cols > n) * ~a.all(axis=1).values[:, None]

df['new1'] = df1.max(axis=1)
df['new2'] = df1.where(mask, 0).max(axis=1)
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6  new1  new2
a  1  0  0  1  1  1     2     2
b  0  0  0  1  0  0     3     2
c  1  0  1  0  1  0     1     1
d  1  1  1  1  1  1     0     0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df1)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
a  0  1  2  0  0  0
b  1  2  3  0  1  2
c  0  1  0  1  0  1
d  0  0  0  0  0  0

print (df1.where(mask, 0))
   1  2  3  4  5  6
a  0  1  2  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  1  2
c  0  1  0  1  0  1
d  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Verify solution with only `0` row:

```
print (df)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
a  1  0  0  1  1  1
b  0  0  0  0  0  0 <- only 0 row
c  1  0  1  0  1  0
d  1  1  1  1  1  1

a = df == 0
b = a.cumsum(axis=1)
df1 = (b-b.where(~a, axis=1).ffill(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int))

cols = np.arange(len(df.columns))
n = np.argmax(df.values, axis=1)[:, None]

print (df1)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
a  0  1  2  0  0  0
b  1  2  3  4  5  6 <- count all 0
c  0  1  0  1  0  1
d  0  0  0  0  0  0

print (df1.where(mask, 0))
   1  2  3  4  5  6
a  0  1  2  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0  0 <- correct not count this row
c  0  1  0  1  0  1
d  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Great. The result is just what I was looking for and get to know new ideas of using where & mask.